# WebHDFS return empty response for jQuery but not in curl

Tags: jquery, hadoop, curl, hdfs, webhdfs

After enabling WebHDFS, accessing through curl command works, but the same request when made through ajax, gives empty response.

For example, "NOTICE.txt" is a file added to HDFS and "new" is a new directory created in root location of HDFS.

```
curl -i -X GET http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1/NOTICE.txt?op=GETFILESTATUS&user.name=hadoop
```

For ajax i tried both:-

```
var url = 'http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1/NOTICE.txt?op=GETFILESTATUS&user.name=hadoop';
$.get(url, function(resp) {
   console.log(resp);
});
```

(and)

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://localhost:50075/webhdfs/v1/NOTICE.txt?op=OPEN&user.name=hadoop',
    dataType:'application/json',
    success: function(resp) {
        console.log(resp);
    },
    type:'GET'
});
```

The curl command works whereas the ajax receives an empty response with the status code 200.
When tried hitting same url through a rest client like POSTMAN, it worked! So, why does the ajax call not work?? 
Should we pass any extra params when calling webHDFS rest api through javascript ajax?

RESULT of curl:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Expires: Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT Set-Cookie:
>   hadoop.auth="u=hadoop&p=hadoop&t=simple&e=1412285804171&s=EmNooXqRZRuQLsMoz3AXP83+7zg=";Path=/
>   Content-Type: application/json Transfer-Encoding: chunked Server:
>   Jetty(6.1.26)
>
> {"FileStatus":{"accessTime":1412246288609,"blockSize":67108864,"group":"supergroup","length":101,"modificationTime":1412246288609,"owner":"vivek","pathSuffix":"","permission":"644","replication":1,"type":"FILE"}}

But the ajax shows:
[image]

Headers of request & response:
[image]

Comment: compare the request headers for ajax and curl

Comment: ajax always gets "application/octet-stream", even if mentioned in request as "application/json" is expected. But curl/postman receives json even if not mentioned. This is the one which is wierd!! Why Jquery is not able to get the correct response when the URL is same. (even when that URL is hit in browser, it gives json response correctly)

Comment: Can you post the request headers of each. Not response but request.

Comment: now added the request and response header screen shot in question above.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but can you post the  view source of the request header of the Ajax and the plain browser get please

Comment: If we hit the url in browser, it will download the file mentioned in path. In the Chrome POSTMAN rest client, it will display the contents of that file.